# CSS Grid, Autofill and auto-sizing of grid cells

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create a button bar component that layouts a couple of buttons in a single row if there is enough space and starts to stack the buttons vertically if there is not enough horizontal space. I am using CSS grid for this:

```
.button-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(12em, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

Now there is the problem that in the minmax expression I have to accomodate for the largest possible button in my application. What I really would like to have is something like `minmax(auto, 1fr)`. That is when buttons are stacked vertically the columns could have different widths and the column width would be as large as to fit the largest button in that column. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: it would be better if you'd include the markup, or some sort of preview of what you want it to look like

Comment: added a picture of the desired layout

Comment: @pesche666 What does it mean "stack the buttons vertically"?  What does that look like because your picture has them wrapping.  I thought you meant like a menu where they stack up under a certain button, straight down, only in that column.

Comment: @johnny When there is enough horizontal space the five buttons in the image above would be layed out in one row. When you shrink the browser window and there is not enough space for all five buttons the "Test" button would go into the second row, if you shrink the window further the "Cancel" button would go to the second row too, and so on.

Comment: @pesche666 As your code is now, the desired "stacking" as mentioned above should be happening.  I'm assuming that you're wrapping your buttons in a div with the class `.button-bar`.  What I can't figure out is how to give the buttons auto-width based on the content inside them...  hmmm..

Comment: @Belder, the .button-bar is a div container for the buttons. Yes, I do have some automatic vertical "stacking" this way, but the grid layout does not consider the widths of the buttons at all